# grunt-connect-proxy too much delay in requests

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-connect-proxy

I'm using the proxy in a angular project with a local server and there is an important delay when the proxy is up.

Comparative requests between running and not running the **proxy**:

```
Request --- Proxy --- Server
request1 --- 15.3s --- 602ms
request2 --- 5.8s --- 387ms
```

Why does the proxy have that delay?I think it's too much delay.